# Clustered Index Scan instead of Seek

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a database for a couple of iot-devices. The inputDatas-datatable have more than 6 Mio. rows. All selects are fast. The second table with iotDeviceParameters have only 55 rows - I would say nothing.

I want to make a select over inputdatas with a join to the parameters table but the select creates all the time an *Clustered Index Scan* over the parameter table. So I created an NONCLUSTERED INDEX on that table:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IoTDeviceParameter_TenantId_DeviceId] ON [dbo].[IoTDeviceParameter]
    (
        [TenantId] ASC,
        [DeviceId] ASC
    )
INCLUDE([Input],[MinimumValue],[MinimumDuration],[AggregationType],[EnergyType],[ParameterType],[Total],[Factor])
```

But without effect.

My expectation is, that the select should go to less than 0.010 seconds. Now it is 0.050 seconds but all the time goes to the scan on parameters table.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyPjsl79o

Some ideas?

Comment: As you're doing a `SELECT *` here, does the `INLCUDE` in the above index *include* **every** column in the table `[dbo].[IoTDeviceParameter]` (apart from `TenantId` and `DeviceId` of course).

Comment: The index doesn't cover columns `Name` and `Id` (unless they are in the clustered index key). What is the execution plan like if you restrict the columns selected from `IoTDeviceParameter` to those covered by the index?

Comment: A 55 row table will always do a scan. That is not a problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: BOOM! I should make a small breake. After including ID and NAME into the index, the select takes 0.01 sec. perfect!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that wrong. Now the select using an index seek and no scan.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - If it is a seekable predicate you should generally still see a seek regardless of number of rows. It is still more efficient even if the table fits on a single page as it can still do a binary search on that page rather than read all rows. Its an oft quoted "fact" that SQL Server will just scan very small tables rather than seek but I've very rarely seen this happen in practice.

Comment: Just valdiating @MartinSmith 's comment with an example of a seek on a table with a "meagre" 11 rows: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RW13cqG6)

Comment: FWIW, the query you have (extracted from the plan) looks a little weird to me. You're specifying both TennantID and DeviceID as predicates in your JOIN clause but then specifying values for both values for both tables in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Try using a FORCESEEK hint and you may actually find that takes longer...

Comment: You said the table has 55 rows which is what my statement is based on. But your query plan says it has at least 226,000.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Nope the execution plan shows the table cardinality has 53 rows. It reads 226,522 rows because the scan is on the inside of a nested loops and executed 4,274 times When the scan is replaced with a seek the rows read will be 12822 (4274 * 3). This is basically doing a cross join as Ben points out. `(IoTDeviceParameter where TenantId = x and DeviceId = y) cross join   (InputDatas where TenantId = x and DeviceId = y)`

Comment: @MartinSmith Again I have learnt some new things, thankyou. Interesting that table cardinality is buried in the XML not in the tooltip.